# Regex in python to get values from multiple lines

Tags: python, regex

I have string in following format and needs regex to get address values. example lines are following,

```
var address = 'Uhartia, 64220 Gamarthe, France';
var address = 'Eaux Chaudes
Place de l\'Eglise, 64440 Laruns, France';
```

I need regex in Python.

Comment: What do you want to extract from these lines? Additionally, this seems to be some `JavaScript` commands, is `Python` really what you're looking for? As of now it seems you could easily split on the `,` to get the different parts.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it is JavaScript statement. I am extracting information from HTML using Python and Scrapy. I need to extract address value from this using Regex.

Comment: Sorry, i did not understand your last comment.

Answer (score 1):

This will get the quoted text (*in capture group 1*)

`address\s*=\s*'([^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*)'`

Expanded

```
 address \s* = \s* 
 '
 (                             # (1 start), Single quoted text
      [^'\\]* 
      (?: \\ [\S\s] [^'\\]* )*
 )                             # (1 end)
 '
```

Comment: when i put this regex in re.findall('your regex', "source html"), it says there is error in regex.

Comment: The regex is not in error! Show the code and the error .. This is a raw string.

Comment: re.findall("address\s*=\s*'([^'\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\]*)*)'", response.body)

Comment: it fixed by adding one more slashes address\s*=\s*'([^'\\\]*(?:\\[\S\s][^'\\\]*)*)

Comment: @user2989777 - You did not show your own attempted regex in your question. This is not a request for work board where you place special orders. No where in my answer did I convert the regex to a language string for you. It's time for you to do some work, eh ? ...